# Read frame from Gstreamer buffer to SDL_Texture

Tags: c++, sdl

I (try to) use gstreamer to play video in SDL 2.

Here is the code of my function where I want to update SDL_Texture:

```
static GstFlowReturn on_buffer (GstAppSink * sink, gpointer user_data)
{
  GstBuffer* sample = gst_app_sink_pull_buffer(sink);
  GstCaps* caps = gst_buffer_get_caps (sample);
  if (!caps) g_print ("could not get snapshot format\n");
  GstStructure* s = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, 0);
  gint width, height;
  int res = gst_structure_get_int (s, "width", &width)  | gst_structure_get_int (s, "height", &height);
  if (!res) g_print ("could not get snapshot dimension\n");
  //printf("caps struct=%s\n", gst_caps_to_string(caps));

  SDL_Rect r{0, 0, width, height};
  SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTexture(RENDER, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);

  if (SDL_UpdateTexture(tex, &r,GST_BUFFER_DATA(sample),(width*4)) == 0)
  {
      printf("ok texture update\n");
  }
  else
  {
       printf("SDL_textureupdate failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
  }

  if ( SDL_RenderCopyEx(RENDER, tex, NULL, &r,ROTATION,NULL,SDL_FLIP_NONE) == 0)
  {
      printf("ok rendercopy \n");
  }
  else
  {
       printf("SDL_ rendercopy failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
  }

  SDL_RenderPresent(RENDER);
  gst_buffer_unref(sample);
  SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
  sleep(0.5);
  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}
```

I don't have any error, but there is nothing in my screen. The Gstreamer Appsink seems to be working, because the video what I play is 2 seconds 30FPS and the on_buffer callback is being called 60 times.

Comment: Why is the `pitch` argument to `SDL_UpdateTexture()` 4086 and not 4096 (1024*4)?  Why are you ignoring the frame `width`/`height` values you query from GStreamer?  How do you know `GST_BUFFER_DATA(sample)` contains planar YUV?

Comment: @genpfault [gstreamer manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gst-plugins-libs/0.10/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsink.html#gst-app-sink-pull-buffer) says it contains the raw videoframe